# objective-c programmatically change table view from standard to grouped?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios4

The following situation pertains to an iPad app I am working on for my company.

So I have an array of type "Person" that holds the information of a list of people.  On the initial page, I have a table that displays their name and picture.  When this loads, the results are ungrouped.  I was wondering if there was a way to easily group these results with the click of a button based on something like location or business title.  The reason they are not grouped when they are loaded is because the powers higher then I deemed it necessary to display the raw list first.  Any ideas on doing something like that?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use "sections" to split the table.

First you need to sort your datasource into the desired groups, and then reflect it in the view.

A dictionary can easily represent the grouped data. Model each group as an array that contains the entries for that group, and then add it to the dictionary with a key that represents the section.

When the data is ungrouped, you can still use the dictionary, but with a single entry, rather than many, and then reflect that in the UI.

That way when you're asked how many sections there are in the table you can return `[dictionary count];` and then when you're asked for the number of rows, you can do something like `[[dictionary objectForKey@"myKey"] count];`

And so on.

When you've reconfigured your datasource you can call `[self.tableView reloadData];` to reload the table with the sections.

Comment: This is a really good idea.  I am going to give it a shot and get back to you.  Thanks!

Comment: Ok I have the data all separated as desired, now I just need to reconfigure the table.  How do you go about changing the table # of sections?  Or pretty much any of the table attributes.  I have found a bunch of ways to do that when the page loads but nothing to do it at runtime.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Calling `reloadData` on the table view will instruct it to query the `dataSource` and `delegate` again for the updated information. You need to manage the state in your controller and conditionally change the number that you return in `numberOfSections...` and `numberOfRows...` etc.

Comment: Alright, this is where it gets kind of complicated.  I am actually building up the table cell by cell based on the content of my person array.  There isn't a delegate or datasource or anything like that.  Should I try to figure out how to substitute in the grouped dictionary instead of using the data directly?

Comment: It would be less complicated if you used the dataSource and delegate. The table view is intended to be used with a data source and delegate. You're just making life harder for yourself by not using them.

Comment: Ok, well each cell is dynamically populated with stuff for each person.  Does that matter?

Comment: Nope, you can populate the cell in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` data source method that you will implement.

Comment: Ok awesome,  

So I took this basic idea and played with my parameters a bit.  Instead of trying to group a table by the filter, I had the user go one level deeper and select the filter they wanted specifically, and then just pushed a new table out.  A lot easier then what I was trying to do.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to remove the UITableView and add another in it's place via `[[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];`. You can't change an existing style at runtime.

The other way to do it, is have it grouped from the get-go, but return 1 for `- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;` if it is "ungrouped" and return all rows for `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` when it is grouped, do it the normal way.

Comment: How would you call those methods again once the user clicks the group button?